# chosen not working to google ajax

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-chosen, google-ajax-api

i have used **Chosen Select** for my website, I'm using bootstrap framework.
if include

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

ajax google api, its not suggesting

this is my code

```
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chzn-select form-control" tabindex="1">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="United States">United States</option>
                    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
                    <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="chosen/ajax.googleapis-1.3-compressed.js"></script>  
    <script src="chosen/mootools-more-1.4.0.1.js"></script>
    <script src="chosen/chosen.js"></script>
    <script src="chosen/Locale.en-US.Chosen.js"></script>
    <script> $$(".chzn-select").chosen(); $$(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({allow_single_deselect:true}); </script>
</body>
```

can anyone tell me how to solve this problem

Comment: I am not sure but why are you using double dolar signs

Comment: i have downloaded from here [ http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen ], they are given like this

Comment: Hmm check and tell what does the console window shows ?

Comment: !!! empty ??? there are no any error messages :(

Answer (score 0):

Rather try using

```
<script> $(".chzn-select").chosen(); $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({allow_single_deselect:true}); </script>
```

Comment: no brother it's not working, if i remove $, styles also notworking